# Cumulative distribution function and density

Tags: probability-theory

I want to prove that when we have probability distribution $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}$ and if $F$ is cumulative distribution function of $\mu$ and $F$ is given by 
$F(t)=\int_{-\infty}^tg(x)dx$, for some function g, then g is density of $\mu$. I have only problem to prove that integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}}g(x)dx$ exists. Because if we know that this integral exists then $\int_{\mathbb{R}}g(x)dx=\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-\infty}^tg(x)dx=1$ and then I know how to prove the rest.

Comment: But $F$ is bounded (by $1$, no probability exceeds one) ___EDIT___ and it is increasing towards that limit, I mean $\lim_{t\to+\infty} F(t) =1$. And so $g$ is non-negative (almost everywhere).

Comment: Yes I know this but how to prove from this that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}g(x)dx$ exist?

Comment: But how to prove that g is nonnegative?